# How can i delete the first half of a text file after the file has reached a certain size limit?

Tags: linux, bash

I am using bash and I have a log text file that saves output and want to delete the first half of the text file once it reaches a certain size limit so that i don't run out of space. the closest i came to solving was using the `truncate` command:

```
find /home/Ryan/Documents -type f -size +20c -exec truncate --size 10 "{}" \;
```

This worked well but the problem is that it deletes the bottom most recent texts but instead i want the top older texts to be deleted.

or if this is not possible then would i be able to run a command like:

```
sed -i '1,5d' log.txt
```

after the file reaches a certain file size?

Comment: Why do you have the command in backticks? That will try to execute the output of the command as another command. But since there's no output, nothing will be executed.

Comment: There is a standard service you could use called `logrotate` which does something similar.  Or you could set up your service as a systemd unit and then systemd would take care of the details of storing the logs.

Comment: `truncate` removes the end of the file, not the beginning. There's no built-in way to remove the beginning of a file. You can use the `tail` command to read the end of the file, write it to a new file, then rename that file.

Comment: Doing this correctly is difficult (because of the details of how files and open file descriptors work), so you're better off using some existing system to do this (e.g. `logrotate` or systemd's log handling) rather than trying to figure out how to do it yourself.

Comment: Or you could pipe the output to system logger `find .... | logger` and let the system figure it that "run out of space" problem out. Then query the output using `journalctl` or from the files (if using rsyslog).

Comment: There are some Linux-only extensions that are only compatible with specific filesystems (mostly btrfs) that can _sort of_ allow parts of a file to be deleted in place without needing to rewrite content you're moving to the front, but in general, it's simply not allowed at all using standard-defined semantics. Use `logrotate` or one of its many equivalents or competitors.

Comment: (the "sort of" covers a bunch of constraints like "only able to operate at page boundaries" that make the aforementioned extensions unsuitable for text files anyhow; they're more a facility for purpose-defined binary file formats).

Comment: Your `sed` command creates a new file, written from the beginning, and then renames it over the old one. It's inefficient and breaks things if anything is trying to append to the log at the same time.